How to resset laravel ui password
Resset password using laravel ui package and send email by Gmail
we have used laravel ui package for authentication and Gmail for sending password reset link email this worked properly in our local server in xampp but when we deployed the project to cpanel this didn't work even shows (We have emailed your password reset link). but we do not receive the email.
.env settings for sending emails using Gmail.
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME="secret"
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret  
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="secret"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"



Try to run artisan config:clear on your production.
And make sure you are using the generated app password, not your account password.
It's better to use smtp rather than sendmail
To do so, make sure you create a password for your app, google no longer trusts apps that use the account main password, and it's more secure to create a specific password for your Laravel app.
Go to your account settings on the Security tab, Enable 2FA first, then search for App Password and generate a new one.
I believe this is the best configuration for .env
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=your@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD= your_app_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=your@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"


Thanks i generated a new password for my app but this times shows the following error
Share with Flare
Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Network is unreachable)

make sure MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Thanks a lot dear i have generated new password for my App and i have used sendmail instead of smtp now this works properly Thanks a lot from your nice guidelines!!!

Greate, Happy for you
